# What is up with my CD-Rom drive on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, compact-disc, optical-drive, lag

I think this is a specific problem that is very strange. This is my first time on the forum, so I hope I am writing things correctly. I have a computer I built myself and here are the specs:

- ASUS M2A74-AM
- AMD Athlon x2
- 3 GB DDR2 RAM
- Radeon 6670 GDDR5 Video Card (I was having the same problem before installing this card).
- Windows reads my CD drive as: "TSSTCORP CDDVDW SH-S223B" CD drive (speedplus and writemaster writen on phsycal drive, jusat a random no-name drive, SATA)

My CD-ROM drive works fine, but a few weeks after purchase, it started reading disks very slowly and the computer would hang at boot whenever the CD drive was present (although Ubuntu on my other partition did not hang). Whenever I burn something, some files are missing on the disc that dont appear to be missing when I burn something on my other computer (using an LG brand Parrell ATA CD-ROM) and that computer does not hang on boot, dispite how old it is! I think it might be a problem with my XP drivers (I did not load any drivers from a CD because there was no drivers on the CD that came with the drive but there was Nero 8 Pro :) ) that are built into the install (Microsoft's drivers).

Please help me!!!

Comment: If you burn things in Linux, it works perfectly??

Comment: CD drives don't have separate drivers that you can install in Windows.  This is by design.  The built in ones are the ONLY ones.

Comment: just basic troubleshooting. Try another drive, if it works then that drive you have is broken.

Comment: I think my drive as partly defective. I am not having the hanging problem anymore, but the drive still reads and writes very slowly, probably because the drive is some no name garbage :/ .  Ow well I don't use optical drives that much anyways so I don't really care that much I just wanted to fix the hanging problem.